# What is an epad in SIM MFF2 layout

Tags: pcb, kicad, sim

I found a Kicad model for SIM MFF2 on the web that I wanted to use in my project but I don't know what is EPAD pin and how to connect.

[image]

EPAD is this central biggest pad on the right image. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It stands for **e**xposed **pad**. They're intended for PCB heatsinking; you solder it to a large copper plane to pull heat away. They're often, but not always, internally connected to ground--look at the datasheet to see what it's connected to for this particular chip.

As an aside, if you're using a chip with an exposed pad, you should definitely use solder paste. Hand-soldering is pretty much not an option.